# What does a database structure of topic id's look like?

Tags: php

I am creating a forum for practice but I am stuck on how to do the topics. Do I need a seperate topic table, and If yes why, cant I just check them in the posts table?

Also, do I record the topic id or the topic name, and if it is the Id, how do I switch them?

Thanks a lot, I am working in PHP

Comment: This seems more like a DBA question

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create topics table separate with unique id this should be like this

```
Topic_id  |   topic_name
1         |   PHP
2         |   Ajax


Post_table
id | topic_id | Post_Title | Post_Detail
1  |  2       |  title     |   post detail text
2  |  1       |  title     |   post detail text
```

and when you are showing posts on pages so you have to do it in mysql_query

Why we use separate table for topics because if 3 post related to topic php and 5 posts related to topic ajax so we can figure our actual data calculation. and best is this do it with separate tables.

Comment: Thanks, adeel, you have drawn it up nice and clear for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you with topic mean like categories in the forum you should definitely have a separate table for the topics. There are loads of reasons to why, but here are a few:

1. For the purpose of normalization of the db
2. A lot easier to maintain if you want to change the name of a topic for instance.
3. Avoids unnecessary data as you don't store the name of the topic for every question.

You store the topic id along with each post that is stored, so that you know which topic the specific post belong to.